# Avoiding MySQL Connection Per Request in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

We use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (which uses MySqlConnector under the hood) to establish a MySQL connection using a typical DbContext approach in Entity Framework.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseMySql(_mysqlConnectionString, _mysqlVersion, b =>
    {
        b.UseNewtonsoftJson();
    })
);
```

We then use dependency injection on *some* controllers that require a database connection.  For example:

```
public class ClientController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public ClientController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

This works fine.  However, we have some controllers that do not require any MySQL connection since they do not interact with the database.  An example would be getting the server time.  We wrap this in its own controller with no dependency injection:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("client")]
public class SimpleClientController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("GetTime")]
    public IActionResult GetTime([FromBody] GetTimeRequest request)
    {
        var response = new GetTimeResponse()
        {
            Time = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        return Json(response);
    }
}
```

However, it appears that a MySQL connection is created for these types of requests as well, which surprised me.  I thought by using dependency injection we would only create a DbContext when required by the controller.  Reading online suggests that a DbContext may, in fact, be created for *every* request, regardless of the controller being utilized.  However, I'm having trouble finding definitive answers, so I'm hoping stack overflow can help here.  For example, the documentation doesn't make it clear if just a DbContext is created (without establishing a connection), etc.  I am curious if the inclusion of Pomelo's MySQL framework is changing the default behaviour here, and maybe they create a connection on DbContext creation?

My questions:

1. Is it true that a MySQL connection will be created due to the creation of a DbContext per request (regardless of whether the request will utilize a controller that injects the DbContext)?
2. Is there a simple way to fix this?  I would like to only create a MySQL connection for requests that require one.  I am currently exploring using DbContextFactory instead on DbContext - which seems like it would do the trick, but will require a large code change.
3. Any other comments related to this would be helpful.

Comment: That sound fishy. Why do you think or how do you found out that SimpleClientController  will somehow create a DbContext that then also will instantiate a MySqlConnection?

Comment: There's nothing to fix. Socket connections to the server are pooled. You don't need to worry about connection *objects*.

Comment: _"I am currently exploring using DbContextFactory instead on DbContext "_ - actually you can use `DbContextFactory` without changing the client code - context instances will be pooled also (socket connections to the server are pooled as mentioned above)

Comment: 1) We had a degradation of our database yesterday which made all of this apparent.  We ended up maxing out our database for a few minutes during peak load, which caused several requests to `SimpleClientController` to fail as well.  We also saw elevated response times for `SimpleClientController` which suggested that those API endpoints were retrying to get a database connection.  That `SimpleClientController` API requests failed during a database degradation surprised me as they have no DbContext injection.
2) Doesn't matter if they're pooled, I still hit max connections due to the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *For example, the documentation doesn't make it clear if just a DbContext is created (without establishing a connection)*

Actual database connections are pooled, see this quote from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cexpression-api-with-constant):

> Note that context pooling is **orthogonal to database connection pooling, which is managed at a lower level in the database driver**.

And this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11496):

> Unless you've disabled pooling (by setting Pooling=false in your connection string), opening and closing connections has negligible overhead and there shouldn't be any reason to avoid it. When a connection is closed it is returned to the pool, and when one is opened it is taken from the pool. This is the default/recommended way to work, rather than trying to implement your own connection reuse.
> Npgsql (and other ADO.NET drivers) has a high-performance pool (the upcoming 4.0 version improves performance even more in this area).

So you should not be concerned that much about the connection object creation

2. *I am currently exploring using DbContextFactory instead on DbContext*

As [DBcontext pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cexpression-api-with-constant#dbcontext-pooling) doc states (also relevant for the previous point):

> A DbContext is generally a light object: creating and disposing one doesn't involve a database operation, and most applications can do so without any noticeable impact on performance.

Note that you can wrap the factory usage so end user code will not change (similar to the sample in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cexpression-api-with-constant#managing-state-in-pooled-contexts)):

```cs
serviceCollection.AddPooledDbContextFactory<YourContext>(...);
serviceCollection.AddScoped(sp => 
    sp.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<WhatsNewContext>>().CreateDbContext());
```

Comment: "A DbContext is generally a light object: creating and disposing one doesn't involve a database operation, and most applications can do so without any noticeable impact on performance." I am not seeing this in reality - it seems like the creation of this DbContext (even for controllers that do not DI a DbContext) is a heavy operation that, if the db is under load, causes my API to slow way down.

Comment: "When a connection is closed it is returned to the pool, and when one is opened it is taken from the pool." The problem is that if every request (even ones that don't use a DbContext) create a connection then I have all of these open connections I shouldn't require.  Yesterday this culminated in maxing out my database connections via API requests that should never have required a database connection to begin with.

Comment: @Giawa - we need the repro then. I have not tested with the MySQL but resolving DbContext does not trigger a database request for me with Postgres (I have provided an invalid connection string). The connection rotation AFAIK happens on per request basis (i.e. EF only actually gets a connection when the request to database is performed).

Comment: I tried the same thing as you (invalid connection string) and I do get an exception generated when trying to request client/GetTime due to attempted dependency injection (despite not using a DbContext in that controller).  This sounds like perhaps a Pomelo issue then, and not an EF issue?

Comment: @Giawa sounds like it. Can you please provide a small [mre]? I will take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Argh, I figured it out.  Thanks for the idea of providing an invalid connection string, the stack trace contained all the info I needed.  Our authorization handler (which runs before any controller) was the one performing the DI of the DbContext.  It doesn't need a DbContext, so I removed that DI and now everything works as expected.  Thanks for the help!